# Next.js. Where to put a global provider?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with Next.js and I need to implement i18n. It requires me to add some global provider that should wrap the whole app. Also, it must receive updates from some state management (eg. Redux) to properly re-render the whole app when the active Language changes.

In the standard React app we have App.js that we put into index.js and keep all logic/providers here.

But in the case of Next, I'm not sure where to put this logic. I double-checked their documentation but I didn't find any mention about it.
Only about [_app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) and [_document.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)  but actually both don't have a possibility to be connected to Redux, etc. Actually they weren't designed for this.

I'm just curious if Next provides some official way to do it or should I just manually create some HOC as App just and wrap the whole app by myself?

Btw. I barely understand the difference between **_app** and **_document**. So I'll appreciate any clarification as well!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation more carefully then, you can find *`Keeping state when navigating pages`* on the second point [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).
That's what redux used for.

I'm able to connect my entire app to redux and i18n from `_app.js` file. In my previous project, my teammates even use `_document.js` file to connect i18n.

As you can see from their doc, the purpose of this `_app.js` is to *override and control the page initialization*. So, you can receive updates from redux and put the changes on `IntlProvider` right before rendering your page.

Other solution is like what you have said, by creating some HOC to wrap your app.

The choice is yours.

Comment: Hi Darryl, thank you for your answer. So there is no difference between _app.js or some Hoc ? I'm wondering about SSR in the case of _app.js approach.

Comment: Does this still apply for the new [app router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)?

Answer (score 0):

To documentation for doing this is here:

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#rendering-third-party-context-providers-in-server-components

1. Create a providers.tsx folder and make sure it has `use client` at the top.
2. Use that providers file in your top level layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `next-connect-redux` package.

[Github page](https://github.com/huzidaha/next-connect-redux)
[Example repo](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, it's useful package,  but I was wondering about where to put such things =)

Comment: Please, look at the example repository.