# useShoppingCart - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe API and use-shopping-cart for a e-commerce site but I have run into this error that I can't seem to figure out, if I wrap a page with CartProvider that single page works with the shoppingcart but I am trying to use it globally throughout the application. So I wrapped the entire app with CartProvider but now I am getting this error. I have read through the use-shopping-cart docs but can't find a solution.

--relevant code--

```
_app.tsx

import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { CartProvider, DebugCart } from "use-shopping-cart";
import * as config from "../config";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

const Cart = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => (
  <CartProvider
    cartMode="checkout-session"
    stripe={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY as string}
    currency={config.CURRENCY}
    shouldPersist={false}
  >
    <>{children}</>
  </CartProvider>
);

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Cart>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Cart>
  );
}
```

this works but only for this single page

```
"use client";
import { NextPage } from "next";

import Cart from "./Cart";
import CartSummary from "./CartSummary";
import Products from "./Products";

const Checkout: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Cart>
        <CartSummary />
        <Products />
      </Cart>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

I am stuck, any help would be appreciated. I get this error when I try and use useShoppingCart throughout the application for adding, removing products and checkout. when I only do this in a single page it works but I need to use this throughout the app.

Comment: Interesting question.  I’m not sure what’s wrong because it seems like `_app.ts` Is the correct place https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61518716/next-js-where-to-put-a-global-provider

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in order to use global variables in next 13 you need to first create your provider file mark it as a client component and then wrap your layout file.

```
"use client";
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { CartProvider } from "use-shopping-cart";
import * as config from "../../config";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!
);

const Cart = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => (
  <CartProvider
    cartMode="checkout-session"
    stripe={stripePromise as unknown as string}
    currency={config.CURRENCY}
    shouldPersist={false}
  >
    <>{children}</>
  </CartProvider>
);

export default Cart;
```

--layout--

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import Cart from "./Provider/Cart";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      {/* <head /> */}
      <body>
        <Cart>
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </Cart>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  to solve it.

I got the same error in Next 13 project. whlie using useShoppingCart. it would give "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch').

I had fogotten to wrap arround components in the layout.jsx/js once i added it as follows the error got resolved.

```js
<Providers>
    <div>
        <SiteHeader />
        <SiteBlob />
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
        <SiteFooter />
    </div>
</Providers>
```